# $watch and $parse in AngularJS code don't work

Tags: angularjs, parsing, watch

I saw this code example in an AngularJS guide. But when I try to run it, it doesn't really work. Can anyone explain me why?

**html file:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input ng-model="expr"
           type="text"
           placeholder="Enter an expression" />
    <h2>{{ parsedValue }}</h2>
</div>
```

**JS file:**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller('MyController',
function($scope, $parse) {
    $scope.$watch('expr', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            // Let's set up our parseFun with the expression
            var parseFun = $parse(newVal);
            // Get the value of the parsed expression
            $scope.parsedValue = parseFun(scope);
        }
    });
});
```

I attached a [link with code that can be run](http://jsbin.com/UWuLALOf/1/edit).

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details: For what input do you expect what result and what are you actually seeing?

Comment: I expect that when I type any text into the "input" region (ng-model = "expr") this text will appear in the "parsedValue" expression.
But for some reason does not appear anything

Comment: The example shown in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) works for me (1+2 yields 3). So what do you expect?

Comment: I give link to the exemple that do not work http://jsbin.com/UWuLALOf/1/edit

Comment: The example jsbin seems to work just fine. You need to describe your problem better.